# why this setState is not firing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I'm trying to build a notification React component for my application that I can call from anywhere. I have the below code where I'm trying to do some kinda hack for exporting the `showNotif` function

```js
function FloatNotification() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const showNotif = () => {
    console.log(`showNotif is called`);
    setShow(true);
  };

  if (!FloatNotification.showNotification) {
    FloatNotification.showNotif = showNotif;
  }

  return <>{show ? `Showing notification` : `not showing notification`}</>
}

export default FloatNotification;
```

On another file I'm trying to call `showNotif` like below

```js
import FloatNotification from "./FloatNotification";

function MyComponent() {
  const {showNotif} = FloatNotification;
  return <><button onClick={() => showNotif()}>Click Me</button></>
}
```

but the `setState` isn't getting called unexpectedly. I'm getting the `showNotif is called` message in the console. so logically the `setState` should also get called.

I kinda understand it's happening because of how javascript handles reference data type. but I'm not sure what's actually happening behind the scene and how to get my goal

Suggest me if you have any other ideas to build this notification component (something I can call from anywhere in my component tree). Any kind of help will be kudos to me

[NOTE: I'm actually using NextJS and I've added this `FloatNotification` in the `_app.js`. So it's available in all the pages

Comment: `setShow(true)` will indeed be executed, but it's not clear what you expect that to *do* because the `show` state is only used inside the `FloatNotification` component, which you don't appear to have mounted anywhere. In fact it's worse than that because each time one of those components is mounted - which could be lots of times for all we now - it will make its own `setShow` and `showNotif` functions and therefore override `FloatNotification.showNotif`. I have no idea what you're actually trying to do but trying to export internal functions from a component is not the solution.

Comment: `setShow(true)` is not getting executed. I've tried setting `useEffect()` for this, which didn't print anything on the console when I fired the `showNotif` function from another file. And the `FloatNotification` is mounted on all the pages by `_app.js` in NextJS. And I know the hack I've tried isn't recommended at all and that's why I thought to post it on SO. to know why the `setShow(true)` isn't executing and also to know what'll be the recommended approach to getting my goal

Answer (score 0):

`useState` is a special function called "hooks". React hooks are only available when the component is rendered in the VDOM tree.

Since you dosen't render `FloatNotification` as a element, calling setState is unexpected and may has no effects.

There are several ways to achieve what you want without hacking.

First is, lift up notification state to the parent component and inject only the dispatch that changes the state is through the context.

```
const NotificationContext = React.createContext(() => {});

function FloatNotification({ children }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <NotificationContext.Provider value={setShow}>
      {children}
      <>{show ? `Showing notification` : `not showing notification`}</>
    </NotificationContext.Provider>
  );
}

function MyComponent() {
  const setShow = useContext(NotificaitonContext);
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setShow(true)}>
      Show Notification
    </button>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <FloatNotification>
      <MyComponent />
    </FloatNotification>
  );
}
```

Or, you can exposing the handler by [`React.useImperativeHandle`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useImperativeHandle) (commonly not recommended)

Comment: the createContext idea surely works. not sure why I didn't think about that till now. however, as I mentioned, I'm using NextJS here and I've added the `FloatNotification` as a component in the `_app.js` file, which has added this `FloatNotification` on all of my pages. So React not treating this as a rendered element is weird ig. or do I need to know something more here?